# Bayesian compositional regression using ilr

Tags: bayesian, compositional-data

I'm trying to fit a compositional data regression from a Bayesian perspective and using ilr coordinates. Once the ilr is computed for the response variable, a multivariate Gaussian regression has to be fitted in the Euclidean space. My problem is the variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Taking a look to the literature, I have found the paper Egozcue et al., 2012, where it is proven that if we use least squares, the matrix $\Sigma$ has to be diagonal, and any correlation parameter has to be estimated.

My question is, if we use other methods for estimation coming from the Bayesian perspective, $\Sigma$ is also diagonal?

Thank you so much for your comments.
Best wishes.

Egozcue, J. J., Daunis-I-Estadella, J., Pawlowsky-Glahn, V., Hron, K., & Filzmoser, P. (2012). Simplicial regression. The normal model.

Comment: I don't get it: "$\Sigma$ has to be diagonal" literally means *all* correlation parameters are zero.  What, then, do you mean by "has to be estimated"?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your question. In the paper, they lead to the conclusion that they don't need to fit a multivariate Gaussian because, as you point out the elements out of the diagonal are zero, and the correlation parameters are zero. However, they get this conclusion using the least squared method to estimate the regression coefficients. Then, my question is, if we try to solve the initial compositional regression using Bayesian inference, is it fulfilled as well that the correlation parameters are always zero in the Euclidean space?